# Defining the correct include path

Tags: php, include, include-path

I am facing a include path error.
In a file config.php  I am including `include ("./inc/logged_in.php" );` which (logged_in.php) further includes `include ("./include/connect.php" );` but I get a error saying:

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\fileman\filemanager\config\config.php

Now this error may be because config.php and logged_in.php are in different subfolders and my inclusion path is incorrect.
I tried using 
`include ("../../inc/logged_in.php" );` now no error for logged_in.php but error for connect.php:

> > include(./inc/connect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\inc\logged_in.php

My structure for config.php is:

// root

//   |- demo

//   |    |-  fileman

//   |    |    |- filemanager

//   |    |    |   |- config

//   |    |    |   |    |- config.php

My structure for connect.php and logged_in.php is:

// root

//   |- demo

//   |    |-  inc

//   |    |    |- connect.php

//   |    |    |- logged_in.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it:

**/demo/fileman/filemanager/config/config.php**

```
include('../../../inc/logged_in.php');
```

**/demo/inc/logged_in.php**

```
include('connect.php');
```